# How to get or compute actual width of ListBox without Vertical Scrollbar if visible

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox, scrollbar

I wonder how to get or compute actual width of *ListBox* without *Vertical Scrollbar* if visible.

What I want to do is changing width of each items inside *ListBox* without being covered by *Vertical Scrollbar*.

```
Width="{Binding ActualWidth, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}
```

At least, above binding tell me the actual width of *ListBox*, but this one does not handle width of vertical scrollbar.

Is there any good way to solve this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try binding to the `ViewportWidth` property of the containing `ScrollViewer` instead.

Like this:

```
Width="{Binding Path=ViewportWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ScrollViewer}}"
```

Comment: Note that this binds to the ViewportWidth of a CONTAINING ScrollViewer, not the internal one.  While you can probably get away with wrapping a ListBox in a ScrollViewer without adverse consequences, if you do this with TreeView it appears to disable UI virtualization which can cause performance issues with many items.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the default will help you: just don't set `Width` at all!

At least in my case it was totally sufficient to not set the `Width` property. While Mårten Wikström's answer is completely correct I found out my actual problem was I had specified (unnecessarily) `Width` and did this in a wrong way (the same way Aki24x has reported).

This is a simplified case of my example. The solution was to just delete line 4.

```
1  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
2      <DataTemplate>
3          <Border
4              Width="..." 
5              >
```