# How can I bind to a ListBox's viewport width (i.e., width without scrollbar)?

Tags: wpf, layout, binding

I want to bind to my ListBox's viewport width. That is, the width of the content area, not counting the borders or the scrollbar:

- When the vertical scroll bar is visible, I want the width of the area between the left border and the scrollbar;
- when the vertical scroll bar is not visible, I want the width of the area between the left and right borders.

Alternatively, I could make do with with something that tells me whether or not the vertical scrollbar is currently visible.

This is for a control that will be outside the listbox -- I want to position it above the listbox's viewport, and make sure it's always the same width as the viewport. I.e., I want to bind its width to the ListBox's viewport width.

Comment: Possible Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526217/how-to-get-or-compute-actual-width-of-listbox-without-vertical-scrollbar-if-visib

Comment: That solution uses {RelativeSource FindAncestor}, so it would only work from a control that's embedded *inside* the ListBox (e.g. in an ItemTemplate), not for something *outside*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is very specific to the internals of the `ListBox` control template.  In the code-behind you can easily find the `ScrollViewer` and you can then use these useful properties:

- ScrollViewer.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility
- ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth

to control the width of your target control.  But this tight coupling is characterstic of a composite control and if instead you override the `ListBox` control template and include your target control at the beginning you will find that you have complete access to the `ScrollViewer` and its useful properties from XAML and you can associate the widths with a binding without all the problems that trying to maintain independent controls cause.

Comment: That never would have occurred to me. Good call.

Comment: Can you please provide some example code that shows how to achieve the proposed solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "binding Path=Width,ElementName=abc".

if you just want to dock a control on the top of another, you can use Grid as well

Comment: Did you even understand the question? I don't want the total width of the ListBox including borders and scrollbars (and Width would be the wrong thing for that anyway, you'd have to use ActualWidth).