# Binding to a ListView's ViewportWidth

Tags: wpf, listview, binding, width, viewport

I am using an `IMultiValueConverter` to bind the `Width` of a `ListView` column so that it fills up all the remaining space.

I am binding to the `ListView`'s `ActualWidth`, and thus this also includes the width taken up by the vertical scrollbar (which has its `Visibility` set to `Auto`).

I want to get the width of the `ListView`'s `ViewPort` (i.e. the width of the `ListView` minus the width of the vertical scrollbar).

I've tried binding as suggested at [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526217/how-to-get-or-compute-actual-width-of-listbox-without-vertical-scrollbar-if-visi), but I always get a `{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}`.

```
</GridViewColumn.Width>
     <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource widthConverter}">
          <Binding ElementName="lstResults" Path="ActualWidth" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" />
          <Binding ElementName="colPartNo" Path="ActualWidth" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" />
          <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ScrollViewer}" Path="ViewportWidth" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True"/>
     </MultiBinding>
</GridViewColumn.Width>
```

The column which needs to be resized is located within a GridView contained within the ListView.View.

Thanks in advance for your help.