# Listbox - indicate if there are items below without a scrollbar in a listbox WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, touch, scrollviewer

I'm doing touchable wpf application and in listbox I removed scrolls, user can scroll down by panning. This works fine. But I want to notify user somehow (maybe arrow icon or text "There is more items") that there are more items below, so user will know he can scroll down. Any ideas how can I achieve this?

Comment: I believe you can do it by creating an arrow using polygon and show it for few seconds in the beginning and the hide it back again.

Comment: Showing is not a problem I think. The problem is how can i know if there are items below in listbox, not shown on screen?

Comment: try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526217/how-to-get-or-compute-actual-width-of-listbox-without-vertical-scrollbar-if-visi